# Glide - adding header to request

Tags: android, request, android-volley, okhttp, android-glide

Is there a method to add a custom header to request when an image is downloaded?
I can use volley or okhttp in Glide.

I tried adding a cookie to the cookiemanager in okhttpclient, but it didn't help.

Is there a method to debug request response in Glide?

Answer (score 93):

Since [3.6.0](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/tag/v3.6.0) it's possible to set custom headers for each request:

```
GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl("url", new LazyHeaders.Builder()
    .addHeader("key1", "value")
    .addHeader("key2", new LazyHeaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public String buildHeader() {
            String expensiveAuthHeader = computeExpensiveAuthHeader();
            return expensiveAuthHeader;
        }
    })
    .build());

Glide....load(glideUrl)....;
```

Comment: I am still getting this issue  -  com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Unauthorized

Comment: my app is getting crashed..  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must not be null or empty pointing out to he line .build()) ...

Comment: what is the "computeExpensiveAuthHeader()" method do in this script?

Comment: @ArashAfsharpour that's code you define. That `LazyHeaders` example demonstrates how to calculate an expensive header on a background thread, since Glide loads are usually started on the main thread and accessing disk/network would block UI. If you have all the info you need in fast accessible memory, you don't need `LazyHeaderFactory`s.

Comment: It works. If you don't see your headers in your logs, make sure they don't replace anywhere after that.

Comment: @antaki93 just to double-check the validity of the answer: same code works on Glide 4.x in 2022?

Comment: @TWiStErRob yes, Glide 4.13.2. But I didn't use the `LazyHeaderFactory` and `buildHeader()`

Answer (score 17):

Kotlin + Glide 4.10.0

```
val token = "..."
val url = https://url.to.your.image
val glideUrl = GlideUrl(url) { mapOf(Pair("Authorization", "Bearer $token")) }

Glide.with(context)
     .load(glideUrl)
     .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
ImageView imgThumb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_thumb);

GlideUrl url = new GlideUrl("https://your-url.com", new LazyHeaders.Builder()
                .addHeader("User-Agent", "your-user-agent")
                .build());

RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);

Glide.with(mContext).load(glideUrl)
                    .transition(withCrossFade())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .apply(options)
                    .into(imgThumb);
```

The Glide reference is:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

Comment: my app is getting crashed..  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must not be null or empty pointing out to he line .build()) ...

Answer (score 4):

If you can't get Glide to do it, you can use [OkHttp Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

Answer (score 3):

This is late, I think but I put it here for notes for anyone else facing the issue. Here are my code samples (this is for Glide v4):

BaseGlideUrlLoader module:

```
private static class HeaderedLoader extends BaseGlideUrlLoader<String> {

    public static final Headers HEADERS = new LazyHeaders.Builder()
            .addHeader("Referer", UserSingleton.getInstance().getBaseUrl())
            .build();

    public HeaderedLoader(ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> concreteLoader) {
        super(concreteLoader);
    }

    @Override public boolean handles(@NonNull String model) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override protected String getUrl(String model, int width, int height, Options options) {
        return model;
    }

    @Override protected Headers getHeaders(String model, int width, int height, Options options) {
        return HEADERS;
    }

    public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<String, InputStream> {

        @Override public @NonNull ModelLoader<String, InputStream> build(
                @NonNull MultiModelLoaderFactory multiFactory) {
            return new HeaderedLoader(multiFactory.build(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class));
        }

        @Override public void teardown() { /* nothing to free */ }
    }
}
```

Add the HeaderLoader class in the AppGlideModule.

```
@Override
public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
    super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry);

    registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class,
            new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(CustomOkHttpsClient.getTrustedOkHttpClient()
            ));

    // override default loader with one that attaches headers
    registry.replace(String.class, InputStream.class, new HeaderedLoader.Factory());
}
```

My solution is based on link provided here 
https://github.com/TWiStErRob/glide-support/commit/b357427363c28a82495097ec862b82acdf3b4357

The original issue is discussed here https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/471

Thanks to @TWiStErRob

Answer (score 1):

Interceptors sound like a great choice. You can pass in your own instance of an OkHttp client to an [OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/integration/okhttp/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/integration/okhttp/OkHttpUrlLoader.java#L22) and [register](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#register(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderFactory)) the Factory with Glide.

If you want more control, you can also simply fork the [OkHttp ModelLoader](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/integration/okhttp/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/integration/okhttp/OkHttpUrlLoader.java#L17) and [DataFetcher](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/integration/okhttp/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/integration/okhttp/OkHttpStreamFetcher.java), register your forked ModelLoader, and get direct access to the OkHttp client for every request.

Answer (score 1):

```
// make sure it's registered in AndroidManifest.xml as described at https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#including-a-glidemodule
public class GlideSetup implements GlideModule {
@Override public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) { /* no costumization */ }
@Override public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
    glide.register(String.class, InputStream.class, new HeaderedLoader.Factory());
}

private static class HeaderedLoader extends BaseGlideUrlLoader<String> {
    public static final Headers HEADERS = new LazyHeaders.Builder()
            .addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
            .addHeader("App-Agent", APP_AGENT)
            .build();

    public HeaderedLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override protected String getUrl(String model, int width, int height) {
        return model;
    }

    @Override protected Headers getHeaders(String model, int width, int height) {
        return HEADERS;
    }

    public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<String, InputStream> {
        @Override public StreamModelLoader<String> build(Context context, GenericLoaderFactory factories) {
            return new HeaderedLoader(context);
        }
        @Override public void teardown() { /* nothing to free */ }
    }
}
```

}

and then

```
....load("http://....")....;
```

Comment: Take a look at the comments in the issue this was pulled from before using it: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/471. In particular, replacing the String -> InputStream loader will remove default handling of uri and file path strings. Consider instead a custom model type (other than String).

Answer (score 0):

Please read this thread: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/198

It appears as if it will be implemented in the coming release (4.0).